# What are the libraries should use when using WMI 

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wmi

I am working with Visual studio 2008. What libraries should be used when using `WMI`. I have imported many libraries but they don't  work

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
```

I am using these `Namespaces`:

```
using System.Management;
using System.Security;
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.Management.dll and made sure you're not using client profile?

Comment: thank you i fixed it .i haven't added the reference.Your answer fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to add a reference to `System.Management` too.

Please find more information here on this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  article :

Someone faced similar issues and solved it by adding a reference to the `dll`.